# endless scroll Recyclerview reloads page onscroll

Tags: android, infinite-scroll, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement Endless Recyclerview in android and able to load the next set of data On scroll of RecyclerView.

But once I receive new set of data , my recycler activity is getting reloaded and items are displaying from initial data . I have even tried with `EndlessScrollRecyclListener`, but it was same.

Here is the code i'm trying

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) 
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

           new LoadData().execute(0);

            loading = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post what is happening in your LoadData class/activity

Comment: LoadData() is asynctask and it is consuming webservices.